# How can I navigate between links with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get data from a website but to get the data I have to access a link from the home page then get data after that I need to go back to the home page and then repeat the cycle where I access a link, get the data and then go back.

I know how to access the link and get the data but I'd like to know how can I access to the other links and go back to where I was after accessing the first link.

Here is what I currently code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class SsFamilleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ss_famille'
    allowed_domains = ['rexel.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.rexel.fr/frx/browse/category']

def parse(self, response):
    ssfamille = response.xpath("//div[@class='MML2 subDropDownMenu default browse-products-menu categoryList-container']//li//a/@href").get()
    yield {'ssfamille': ssfamille}
    test = response.xpath("//div[@id='facet_category']//div[@class='allFacetValues']//li//label[@class=' facet_leftCheckBox-label']//span/text()").extract()
    yield {'test': test}
    next_page = response.xpath("//div[@class='MML2 subDropDownMenu default browse-products-menu categoryList-container']//li//a/@href").get()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to go back and forth between pages to follow every link on the home page. Instead, select and yield all the home page links in the first place. When selecting multiple links you need to use `getall()` to get all of the matches. `get()` returns only the first match. Then you need to loop over the results:

```
next_pages = response.xpath("//div[@class='MML2 subDropDownMenu default browse-products-menu categoryList-container']//li//a/@href").getall()
for next_page in next_pages:
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```